# Puiseux series over positve charactersitc field

Tags: field-theory, laurent-series, formal-power-series

Let $C((T))$ be the field of formal Laurent series over the algebraically closed field $C$ with positive characteristic. What does the algebraic closure of this field look like?

For instance , if the characteristic is 0, these are the Puiseux series.

Comment: Have you seen this? https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9810142